# Catch return json from POST with Axios when error 400 (Bad Request) occurs

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am making an http request in an api using React Native with Axios, I can get json and parsear it when the callback is 200, however, for example, when I call a method, for example, to register the user and step an email from a user who is already registered, he returns me an error 400 (Bad Request) but he also brings a json with the error message ("user already registered"). I need to get this error message since it is variable in the API and show to the user, but when I try to give it a console.log I get the following error:

[image]

json's return is this:

[image]

and my call code looks like this:

[image]

How to get this json even with return 400 in catch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

inside of your `catch` Block, the `error` object also provides you with a response body

```js
//... your request here
.catch(error => {
  console.log('response: ', error.response.data);
});
```

`console.log(error)` is calling the `toString` method of the error object which doesn't show you the response body.

`error.response.data` should give you the right content. Take a look at [this part of the axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors)